# CAPL - When Button is clicked - program is executed twice

Tags: panel, capl, canalyzer

The code which need to be executed when Button is clicked. It is being executed twice.
when I use "if(this == 1)" I am having an error "Operand types are incompatible"

```
on sysvar_update sysvar::NexteerData::WriteRead
{
      seclevel = 1;
      ExtendedSession.SendRequest();
      toggle2 = 1;
      Write("Write CALIBRATION VALUES");
}
```

Comment: That is correct. What is your question?

Comment: It might be possible that your system variable 'WriteRead' is triggered from multiple files. Kindly check and improve the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are not using the if statement in your snippet. Also, please use formatting for all your text

Answer (score -1):

When using the value of the system variable in an if statement, use as follows:

```
if(@this == 1)
```

This will solve your error and also the double execution issue.